# sum of values in oddly delimited file

Tags: text-processing

I have a scenario where i want to calculate the sum of below data set

```
V1|V2|V3  
"1.1"|"1.2"|"A"
"1.1"|"1.2"|"B"
"1.1"|"1.2"|"C"
```

sum of V1 V2 ?

how to that

output :

```
3.3 3.6
```

Comment: Your question is unclear.  Do you want to calculate the sums of the columns? (V1=3.3, V2=3.6) Or do you want a grand total? (V1+V2=6.9)

Comment: sum of column i did like this not working : sed 's/"//g' | awk -F'|' '{ SUM += $1} END { printf "%.2f",  SUM }' a.txt

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a function to sum the required multiple column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558377/how-to-create-a-function-to-sum-the-required-multiple-column)

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat q
v1|v2|v3
"1.1"|"1.2"|"A"
"1.1"|"1.2"|"B"
"1.1"|"1.2"|"C"
$ sed 's|"||'g q | awk "-F|" \
    'BEG{v1=0;v2=0;}NR>1{v1 = v1 + $1; v2 = v2 + $2;}END{print v1 " " v2}'
3.3 3.6
```

Comment: its not an effective way to do bro need to parametric so that it can work with any file data like need to take column name V1 V2 V3 in parameter form to script incase in future the requirement may be like 5 column sum is needed then script should be able to calculate 5 column sum ... V1 V2 V3 V4 V5

Comment: read my solution at the : https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559767/how-to-calculate-multiple-floating-point-column-sum  ... scroll down till last you will find my solution

Comment: gawk is not awk. Your solution is not portable. Besides, you need bash. Both answers from that thread do. On BSD, that's jut a pain, my answer still stands, while OP did not talk about dynamic columns.