# How to get position of multiple column name

Tags: text-processing, csv

i have a scenario where i want to know in which position number the column name comes

like i have sample data below

```
ID|NAME|S1|BQ|S2|VN|D1
1|vimal|10.12|12.4|56.2|12.2|11.22
2|vilas|10.12|12.4|56.2|12.2|11.22
3|viky|10.12|12.4|56.2|12.2|11.22
```

Colum name : S1 S2 D1

output should be :

```
3
5
7
```

Comment: You can use the same method I described here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/558381/364705

Comment: You changed the expected output format. Now the accepted answer is no longer correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the sample data is in file1:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i"=$"i}}' file1 | grep -E "S1|S2|D1"
```

Using awk, we read only the 1st line and split into multiple columns where it is represented as col vs column number. Using grep, we are filtering only the list we are interested in.

Updated solution since OP changed the output format:

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if ($i ~ /S1|S2|D1/){print i;}}}' file
```

Comment: can you able to get me only values not with colun name question updated pls look

Comment: @ Kusalananda can you able to get me the required output in question updated

Comment: @Thank u so much bro worked as expected