# How do get column position for multiple column names

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a scenario where I want to get column position number

```
ID|NAME|S1|BQ|S2|VN|D1
1|vimal|10.12|12.4|56.2|12.2|11.22
2|vilas|10.12|12.4|56.2|12.2|11.22
3|viky|10.12|12.4|56.2|12.2|11.22

column name : S1|S2|D1
```

Output should be below:

```
3
5
7
```

I tried below code but partially provide output

```
awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i"=$"i}}' demo.txt | grep -E "S1|S2|D1"

S1=$3
S2=$5
D1=$7
```

Need output like below

```
3
5
7
```

Comment: How is this different from [your other recent question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/559783/how-to-get-position-of-multiple-column-name)?

Comment: @Kusalananda i have run previously shared answer but i am passing it in for loop in my script it is iterating all the values from 1 till 6 that y need only 3 5 7

Comment: @Kusalananda my solution not working even though it gives expected output is their any way i can cut only values from S1=$3 to 3 , S2=$5 to 5 and so on

Comment: i have tried this code : awk -F"|" 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){print $i"=$"i}}' demo.txt | grep -E "S1|S2|D1" | sed -r 's/=$/\t/g'

Comment: Context and other clarifications should be added to the question itself, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$ awk -F"|" 'NR==1 {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i=="S1" || $i=="S2" || $i=="D1" ) {print i}}' demo.txt
```

However (I just checked it out), ***@guru***'s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/559786/72707) does the same and is nicer to look at, from my point of view.