# Not able to calculate sum of multiple column where file data in different format .csv

Tags: text-processing, csv

I have a scenario where i want to calculate sum of column

```
SAL|CAL|TAG|VAL
12.11"|"1.1"|"2.1"|"1.1
13.11"|"1.1"|"2.2"|"2.2
14.11"|"1.1"|"2.4"|"2.4
```

**My below code not giving output giving output as 0.00**

I need output for this column CAL VAL

```
awk -F'|' '{T+=$2} END { printf "%.2f\n", T }' demo.txt
```

output :

```
6.7 5.7
```

Comment: The issue is that (outside of the header line) your delimiter is `"|"` not `|` - when you use `|` as the delimiter, the field values become strings like `"1.1"` that evaluate numerically to zero

Comment: @steeldriver how to come accross it any solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a function to sum the required multiple column](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/558377/how-to-create-a-function-to-sum-the-required-multiple-column)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either the delimiters in your file are inconsistent (plain `|` in the header line but `"|"` thereafter) or the delimiter is consistently `|` but the field quoting is inconsistent (missing open `"` on the first field and closing `"` on the last).

Either way, when you set `-F'|'`, the values of `$2` are parsed as strings, like `"1.1"` which get converted to a numeric value of zero when you try to perform addition on them.

If your system's version of awk supports regular expressions for the field separator, you could instead use `-F'"?\\|"?'` which allows the (literal) `|` to have optional leading and trailing quotes:

```
$ awk -F'"?\\|"?' '{T+=$2} END { printf "%.2f\n", T }' demo.txt
3.30
```

Comment: super code worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

From the expected output, you seem to be adding TAG and VAL columns.

I note your input is not valid CSV. You can not-quote fields, like 12.11, or you can quote fields, like "12.11". Half-quoting them is not valid.

Two ways to do this, including avoiding adding "numeric" values from the column headings. (None of this is tested.)

(a) Define a field separator to match the reality.

```
awk '-F"[|]"' 'NR == 1 { next; }
{ T3 += $3; T4 += $4; }
END { printf ("T3 %.2f T4 %.2f\n", T3, T4); }'
```

(b) Fix each field before you use it.

```
awk '-F|' 'NR == 1 { next; }
{ gsub ("\042", "", $3); T3 += $3; }
{ gsub ("\042", "", $4); T4 += $4; }
END { printf ("T3 %.2f T4 %.2f\n", T3, T4); }'
```

If this is an example, and you are planning to do this for more columns, I would probably make T into an array, and the addition into a function:

```
awk '-F|' 'NR == 1 { next; }
function Sum (f) {
    gsub ("\042", "", $(f)); T[f] += $(f);
}
{ Sum(2); Sum(3); Sum(5); Sum(11); }

END {
    for (f = 1; f < 20; ++f)
        if (f in T) printf ("T%d %.2f\n", f, T[f]);
}'
```